# how to add shipping cost calculator on Delivery and returns page in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, php

i would like to show the shipping costs for selected country on the cms page. Does anybody know an extension or solution therefore?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Table Rate shipping method in admin panel for that.
Go to Sttores  -> configuration -> Sales -> Shipping Methods. There you can find Table Rates.

For customize shipping cost change store view to specific store. 
Now You should be able to see Export and Import buttons under "Table Rate".
Like here: https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-table-rates-shipping-method-magento-2.html or here http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/shipping/shipping-table-rate.html

In Magento docs, there is quite nice description how to create csv file for Table Rates.
However You can also check here:
https://www.humcommerce.com/tutorial/table-rates-shipping-magento-2/
and here:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7286
and so on...

There is no really much logic, just use schema ;)

Comment: i want add to cms page of delivery & returns i have already my csv file of shipping rates i just want people to select there country and the price of shipping will show for example have a look at the link what i am trying to achieve  http://www.asos.com/customer-service/delivery/

Comment: It is not default magento functionality. I dont know and I couldnt find any module that provide functionality like that for Magento2.